# Does backbonejs issues 'beforeChange' event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to catch a "`beforeChange`" event, to prepare some stuff before a model's field changes. Does BackboneJS have something like this, or how could I accomplish something similar?

Comment: Looks like just 'change' is thrown if a set operation results in a change of values.  For the functionality you're looking for, I'd overwrite `set`. You could check for your keys ahead of time, throwing the pre event when found, and then defer to the default set behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "`beforeChange`" event—but there are a few ways I know of to accomplish a similar kind of thing.

## 1. Override `model.set`

The easiest thing to do is override [`model.set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set)
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dkho4p2r/

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function (attributes, options) {
        // do stuff here
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

## 2. `model.validate`

You also have access to [`model.validate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate), which—if you pass the `validate: true` option when calling `model.set`—is called before the model is actually changed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dkho4p2r/1/

This probably isn't the best place to put arbitrary code, but it fits the requirement of occurring before the model's `change` event.

## 3. Process input before calling `model.set`

This may be the too-obvious answer you were looking to avoid, but you can always just "prepare some stuff" before calling `set()` on your model.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dkho4p2r/2/

```
data = prepareSomeStuff(data);
model.set(data);
```